# Cloud/hosted push systems which do or can use socket.io as the client?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, publish-subscribe, pubnub

Are there any cloud/hosted push systems which use socket.io on the client side? Systems I know of, none of which use socket.io AFAIK:

- http://beaconpush.com/
- http://pusher.com/
- http://www.pubnub.com/

Are there any services I'm missing? Could any of them be used with socket.io?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Socket.IO** client API on **PubNub**.
Early Access: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/socket.io

```
<!-- SIMPLE USAGE -->
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js></script>
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://pubsub.pubnub.com');
  socket.on( 'news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  } );
</script>
```

[image: Socket.IO Terminal Example]

This simplified usage of Socket.IO will create a connection, listen for a *news* event and log the data to the console.

More Info: [PubNub Website](http://www.pubnub.com/)
Play Video: [Bidirectional JSON Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZgcEj_qKLU)

Early Access: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/socket.io

[image: Socket.IO is Better on PubNub]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the socket.io client with our service (Pusher.com), and I don't imagine you can use it with the others either.

IIRC Socket.io is a fairly tightly coupled combo of client and server, and it doesn't necessarily make sense to only use the client part.

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to do this, but I'm happy to pick it up through our support system, if you think we are lacking functionality.

Max

Comment: Thanks for coming over and answering! I want my code to use the websockets API. socket.io seems to be the most actively developed cross-browser websocket emulator. Keeping such a thing for all browsers and versions running well is pretty complicated, so IMO for at least certain parts of the functionality there should/could be "only one" — kind of like how there is only one easyXDM. (oversimplifying, yes, but that's the sprit of my question)